# Rails 5 - regex - for string not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

In my app that I am building to learn Ruby and Rails, I am working on finding data and am relatively new to regex (studying the mastering regex book). In this case better said: combination of presence and absence of data.

Case: if a document contains a combination of strings, I want to classify its document type.

Assume this content: *delivery note 12345 invoice number 45tr3* versus *delivery note 12345 invoice number 45tr3 credit note 645211*.

How can I figure out in a regex if the term ***credit note*** is absent, while the term ***invoice number*** is present?

If it is absent, it is document type A, if it is present document type B.

Comment: There are several ways (lookarounds or alternation), what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, no concrete ones as of yet. Still a bit in the dark how to get started with this one principally. I can find the terms (easy), yet not sure how to combine. Have been reading about lookaround/behind... yet hard one to understand honestly (am business process person).

Comment: The question I linked to provides a solution to this riddle. It can be done with `/\A(?!.*\bcredit note\b).*\binvoice number\b.*\z/` (the PCRE `^` is `\A` in Ruby regex, and `$` -> `\z`)

Comment: was working on this one (from the linked question) - /(?!.*credit note).*\b(invoice)\b.*/ . and see your is more concise. So, in effect, if no match found (match data object is empty), it is doc type A? (in plain English ;-) )

Comment: Yes, when a regex does not match a string, the matchdata is nil, else, you have an object with the matches.